# Bash - Finding files with repeated number in name

Tags: bash, macos, find

I have a directory with many subdirectories, and I would like to recursively search for jpg files with a repeated number in the name.

Clarification - files have dimensions in name e.g. 300x300, and I want to list only square images. The dimensions are different (i.e. 500x500; 1200x1200 etc.).

I am using Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gnu find` with regex:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\b([0-9]+)x\1\.jpg$'
```

`([0-9]+)x\1` ensures repeat of same digits separated by `x`.

On OSX (BSD) find, you can use:

```
find . -iregex '.*[[:<:]]\([0-9][0-9]*\)x\1\.jpg$'
```

Comment: OS X has BSD `find`, not GNU `find`. It doesn't have `-regextype`.

Comment: Actually I have both. `gnu find` using `home brew` but I just added in answer that it works with `gnu find`.

Comment: Note that this looks for exactly `path/to/300x300.jpg`; you have to fettle the regex to allow `path/to/picture-name-300x300.jpg`, which is probably what the OP is after.

Comment: `egrep` on OSX should support backreferences like `\1`, so you can filter your results from `find` through `egrep` and expect files to match correctly.

Comment: You can use `find . -regex '.*/[^/]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)x\1\.jpg$'` on Mac OS X 10.11.6 to find names such as `./a1/file-100x100.jpg` and `./a1/file-1200x1200.jpg` and not find names such as `./b3/file-100x101.jpg` and  `./b3/file-200x201.jpg`.  Note that the problem is that you need to use `\(` and `\)` to do the capture, rather than the `\1` back-reference not working per se.

Comment: I think this answer is over-engineered. Especially the regex; it needs to loosen up.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's really great. just needed `[[:<:]]` to avoid matching `./130x30.jpg` as a valid match.

Answer (score 1):

The first portion of the pipe finds all of the jpg files within the tree. The second portion of the pipe filters those results.

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' | egrep '[^\d](\d+)x\1'
```

There are ways to extend the regex to support for variants, but according to your description, this should suffice.

Comment: You need to use `grep -E` or `egrep`.

Comment: @barmar my `grep` is aliased to `egrep`. Mea culpa.

Comment: Curious quirk: this selected my test names `./b3/file-303x304.jpg` and
`./b3/file-919x920.jpg`. It's correct: the first matches 3x3 and the second 9x9, but it isn't immediately obvious that that's what is expected.

Comment: Definitely unexpected behavior. Good catch. This could be the antidote: `[^0-9](\d+)x\1`